# Typescript : unnamed call/construct signatures are inherited, but not the others

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I noticed that the unnamed call/construct signatures could be inherited down the inheritance chain, but not the others (ex: named call signatures, aka method calls, are not inherited down the inheritance). However, I could *NOT* find any statements in the "Typescript spec" (could be found in the official Typescript website) about this fact.

After searching the Typescript compiler source codes, I could find a [GitHub patch](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/commit/059b57f41762451086a2a6d6a06254517905248a) at 2014/8/5 to add this "feature". That patch mention that *"Unnamed (call\construct) signatures in interfaces are inherited and not shadowed"*, but I can not find any lines in the spec to describe this.

I wonder if this is an undocumented behavior of the Typescript spec/compiler, or I missed something important in the spec? (and where could I find a complete statements about what would be inherited down the inheritance chain of classes and/or interfaces?)

The following is an example to describe this:

```
class Widget {
    get(key: 'style'): Object;
    get(key: string): any;
    get(key: string): any {
        if (key == 'style') {
            return "aaa";
        }
    }
}

class TextInput extends Widget {
    get(key: 'value'): string;
    get(key: string): any;
    get(key: string): any {
        return "bbb";
    }
}

var a: TextInput;
var b: string = a.get('style');  // it should give me an error, but not.

//=========================================================

interface Widget1 {
    get(key: 'style'): Object;
    get(key: string): any;
}

interface TextInput1 extends Widget1 {
    get(key: 'value'): string;
    get(key: string): any;
}

var a1: TextInput1;
var b1: string = a1.get('style');  // it should give me an error, but not.

//=========================================================

interface Widget2 {
    (key: 'style'): Object;
    (key: string): any;
}

interface TextInput2 extends Widget2 {
    (key: 'value'): string;
    (key: string): any;
}

var a2: TextInput2;
var b2: string = a2('style');  // it indeed give me an error~! good~!
```

Comment: `I noticed that the unnamed call/construct signatures could be inherited down the inheritance chain, but not the others (ex: named call signatures, aka method calls, are not inherited down the inheritance` is fairly vague. Please provide a code sample for a meaningful answer

Comment: Hi, Basarat, I've added example codes to describe this. and you can see this [webpage](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/08/22/advanced-typescript-concepts-classes-types/), on the "Extending subclasses with function overrides" section for similar concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extending an interface with a Function Type you actually reintroducing the function signature. Think of it as the constructor function. The same would happen of you tried to reintroduce the new signature, like this:

```
interface WidgetStatic {
    new(param:number):number;
}

interface TextInputStatic extends WidgetStatic {
    new():string;
}

var textInputConstructor: TextInputStatic;
var instance: number = new textInputConstructor();  // Will give an error is it returns a string
```

The other thing you showed, when overriding an overloaded method in a classes, you actually saying that now you have a different implementation, it makes sense that you have to define what are the overloads that your new implementation support.

You inherited overloads, but you don't if you override them.

A good read can be found [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces) Scroll to "Difference between static/instance side of class"

**Edit (Added specification details):**
You can find the function declaration in [the spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) in Section A.4 there's the definition of how a function is declared, you can see that overloads are part of the definition. So if you override a function (Section 8.3.2), you introduce a new implementation, so all the overloads are not relevant anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why this overload inheritance behavior does not exist for the named signature? like the example codes I posted, 'TextInput1' interface could not see the overloading functions in the base 'Widget1' interface. Could you point me out which lines in the spec mentioned this behavior? Thx in advance.

Comment: Hi, gilamran, thx~! your "added specification details" is the last piece of the puzzle, I can understand all of it now. Thx~!